# Android: Is it possible to scale a xml drawable?

Tags: android, xml, scale, shapes

Here is what I want to do: I have this scale xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/mydrawable" 
    android:scaleGravity="bottom"
    android:scaleHeight="50%" />
```

And I want to use it with this drawable xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFFFF"
                android:endColor="#FFFF0000"
                android:angle="90" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Then I set the scale xml as a background for a LinearLayout, but I don't see anything. Am I missing something or is it not possible to do this (with XML)?

Comment: BTW The top-level element can be 'shape' without needing a layer list to surround it. Also, in which resource directory are these files?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I am coming into this _extremely_ late.

Comment: @michelemarcon: Did you end up with anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an issue with the ScaleDrawable object which cannot be resolved in XML.

But it is easy, just do the following:

```
// Get the scale drawable from your resources
ScaleDrawable scaleDraw = (ScaleDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background_scale);
// set the Level to 1 (or anything higher than 0)
scaleDraw.setLevel(1);

// Now assign the drawable where you need it
layout.setBackgroundDrawable(scaleDraw);
```

I tested your code using this solution and it worked fine.